# Gulp decode php tags (less-than/more-than signs)

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, decode, encode

I'm using [gulp-inline-image-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-image-path) to replace src attributes in images. I'm replacing the image src with a php variable.

```
inlineImagePath({path: "<?= $img_path ?>"})
```

but the output is being encoded..

```
<img src="&lt;?= $img_path ?&gt; />
```

Is it there a way to decode `&lt;` and `&gt;` with Gulp? I am currently using [gulp-html-entities](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-entities) but it decodes the entire file, not specific characters.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. gulp-inline-image-path uses [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) internally, which properly and correctly parses the HTML and sets the img src via DOM methods. Therefore when serialized back to a string, the `<` and `>` will appear (equally properly and correctly) as HTML-escaped. The cleanest solution would be not to use gulp to preprocess PHP source code. There are several choices for server-side HTML templating, maybe it's easier to switch to one of them.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the info! Would it be possible to just use regex afterwards in Gulp to decode?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against that. If you do that, you could just as well use regex only and skip the use of gulp-inline-image-path entirely. Maybe switch to Handlebars or Mustache as your server-side templating language? There are PHP implementations for that. There is also a Jade implementation for PHP. I recommend you try that before rolling your own string replacement scheme.

Answer (score 0):

you're using this inside a gulp task? i'm not sure what you doing, you need place the gulp task inside a "gulpfile.js", if you place php inside, the output will be that showed in your own post.

Comment: Yes it's a gulp taks. in gulpfile.js

Comment: so, it's impossible place php tags in a gulp task, because you php was compiled to html in your browser and then, the javascript runs after that... so, your gulp task it's just placing a string at your img tags